# SQLalchemy: "Chained" building query objects allowed?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm getting spurious errors in a Flask/SQLAlchemy app that I've been unable to reproduce. But in the Apache error logs I see large stack dumps which end like this:

```
"Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

[ .... many lines of stack trace .... ]

"Can't reconnect until invalid "
 sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
 [SQL: SELECT chart.id AS chart_id, chart.anltyp AS chart_anltyp, chart.anlnum AS chart_anlnum, chart.przsrt AS chart_przsrt, chart.tst_art_num AS chart_tst_art_num, chart.regel AS chart_regel, chart.name AS chart_name, chart.anl_name AS chart_anl_name, chart.aktiv AS chart_aktiv_
 FROM chart INNER JOIN clientview ON chart.anltyp = clientview.anltyp AND chart.anlnum = clientview.anlnum_
 WHERE clientview.id = %s AND chart.aktiv != %s]
 [parameters: [{}]]
```

I can't really figure out of the SQL statement is the cause or the effect of this error, but what strikes me as odd is the "parameters: [{}]" bit. It seems that the SQL statement requires parameters, but execution doesn't suppl y any, which shouldn't happen because this is generated by the SQLALchemy ORM. The code in question is:

```
charts = db.query(Chart)
if not new_view:
    charts = charts.join(View).filter(View.id == view_id)
charts = charts.filter(Chart.aktiv != 0).all()
charts.sort(key=key_anlage)
```

I wonder if I'm messing up things by re-assigning stuff to "charts". I'm probably repeatedly creating and destroying a query object. The code is of course easily refactored (with some redundancy) like this:

```
if not new_view:
    charts = db.query(Chart).join(View).\
        filter(View.id == view_id).\
        filter(Chart.aktiv != 0).all()
else:
    charts = db.query(Chart).\
        filter(Chart.aktiv != 0).all()

charts.sort(key=key_anlage)
```

I've just done this, and so far the error hasn't occurred again, but I can be sure only in a day or two. So my questions are:

1) What could be the cause for SQLAlchemy emitting a statement with empty parameters?

2) If it is my code, what would be a more clever way of conditionally add joins to a statement?

Maybe it's the "chart = chart.all()" thing that transforms a query to a list of results and looks a bit silly in hindsight. Of course it's a leftover from the time this whoe thing was just a single, simple query w/o optional filters and joins.

Comment: "I wonder if I'm messing up things by re-assigning stuff to "charts"." you're not, it's something else.